# php open other files locally

Tags: php, localhost

So I have an index.php file and a scrapper.php files in the same directory.
I use my mac terminal in that directory, and launch the php -S localhost:8888.
When I go to localhost:8888, the index.php shows up. Which is great.

However, I also want to see the scraper.php file in my browser but I don't know how. 
Please help me.
So far I've tried:

http://localhost:8888/scraper
(which only shows my index.php).

I also included 
    `<?php include("./scraper.php"); ?>`
in my index.php.

I can see the interaction in my terminal:
[Thu May 14 21:57:43 2015] 127.0.0.1:60411 [200]: /background.jpg
[Thu May 14 21:57:45 2015] 127.0.0.1:60416 [200]: /scraper

But now broswer.
Please help.

Comment: Have you tried with - `http://localhost:8888/scraper.php`?

Comment: How about `<?php include(__DIR__ . "/scraper.php"); ?>`

Comment: ttp://localhost:8888/scraper.php worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sgt BOS's solution worked.
Need to append .php at the end